# CFHTTP error for SSL enabled site

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, coldfusion-11

I am trying to get the response from a site that's on https and I am getting:

```
I/O Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path.
```

I looked for the issue and found that SSL certificate for that needs to be imported so that ColdFusion can use that in order to fix this.

**My question is:**

We are using Let's Encrypt for SSL installation so it's needs to be renewed every 3 months. Do I need to import the certificates everytime a site has been renewed or new certificates were installed?

Can't JVM import that by itself if a resource over https has been requested and the site certificates are valid and not in keystore?

Comment: What version of java is your server running on?

Comment: @Twillen It's 1.8.0_25

Comment: Just update your Java version to 8u101 or newer and you do not need to import lets-encrypt certificates.

Comment: @Twillen Thanks. I will try to update the version and will let you know.

Comment: @Beginner did updating the java version work for you? i'm having a similar issue with lets encrypt with cfimap

Comment: @luke Haven't tried it yet. Can provide more info tomorrow.

Comment: @Twillen Yes, it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @luke Yes, it worked for me.

Comment: thanks @Beginner - glad it worked!